# Remove the 7th digit of a bigint for every row in a Sql Server table

Tags: sql-server

I am maintaining SQL Server database and some c# code which uploads data to it from a third party. The database has a table 'LessonRoom' which contains a row for each lesson which occurs in a particluar room, it has a field 'SourceKey' which is a bigint and is formed by concatenating a room id and a lesson id, the c# which returns this key is as follows:

```
SourceKey = long.Parse(RoomId.ToString().PadRight(7, '0') + LessonId.ToString());
```

This code started falling over because the lessonId's grew too large and the resulting int is too large to fit in a bigint (c# long). The RoomIds are only ever 5 digits long so an easy fix is to `PadRight(6, '0')`.

Now I have a solution but I need to update the existing data. I don't know how to remove a zero from the 7th digit of a SQL Server bigint in every row of 500,000 rows. Do I have to write a query to convert the value to a string, remove the zero, parse and put it back or can anyone think of a more succinct way to do it?

Essentially I need to turn this number:
6,159,800,830,114,069,893

Into this one:
615,980,830,114,069,893

Comment: I think the real question is: why are you stuffing two value into one column?

Comment: @Ben Thul you are completely correct. I am maintaining a piece of code and (unless I am very much mistaken) the original author has done a really stupid thing. They use the column to guarantee a unique 'LessonRoom' but (in the above example) a room id of either "615980" or "61598" would produce the same SourceKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sine you know it is always the 7th character you want to remove you can do this quite easily.

```
declare @SourceKey bigint = 6159800830114069893

select cast(stuff(cast(@SourceKey as varchar(25)), 7, 1, '') as bigint)
```

Comment: All 500,000 rows now have the correct updated key, from a query that ran for less than 10 seconds. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you could resolve them with the modulo-Operator :)
here a simple T SQL example

```
DECLARE @input AS BIGINT 
DECLARE @expect AS BIGINT 
DECLARE @rest AS BIGINT 
DECLARE @result AS BIGINT 
DECLARE @resultShort AS BIGINT 

SET @input = 6159800830114069893 
SET @expect= 615980830114069893 

SET @rest = @input % 1000000000000 

SET @result = ( ( @input - @rest ) / 10 ) + @rest 
SET @resultShort = ( ( @input - @input % 1000000000000 ) / 10 ) + @input % 
                   1000000000000 

SELECT @rest, @result, 
       CASE 
         WHEN @result = @expect THEN 'true' 
         ELSE 'false' 
       END AS test, 

       @resultShort, 
       CASE 
         WHEN @resultShort = @expect THEN 'true' 
         ELSE 'false' 
       END AS test2
```

[image: SQL Output]

Comment: This is, in many ways, a cleverer solution than the one I ended up accepting, thanks for your time.